# Symfony 3 - set Error Message for a field in a form, after reset the value of this field via Doctrine LifecycleCallbacks

Tags: php, events, doctrine-orm, symfony

there is a form with some fields. Before a save (PreUpdate) i check the data with Doctrine LifecycleCallbacks. If there is a special condition, the value goes back to the old entry. That all works fine for me.

But now, i want to let the user know about this fact. The best and most transparent way is to throw an error/message for this field.

How can i do this?

I know, the entity is the wrong place to call a message service or other things. But maybe i can set an error via Dotrine?
$em->setError("fieldname", "Error") or something else that bubbles up to the form creator?
Is there also a possiblity to abort the save completely?

Thank you for reading and maybe helping.

Comment: Move your lifecycle callback to a custom validation constraint and check it there; not only will it prevent the update but it will set the form error and message for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the validation component and validate your entity before saving !

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

And maby write a custom validator :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html